# Azure AD JWT Token Error in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt

I have react app, which can login user via Azure AD. After that, I created from react app request into my .net core mvc app with header Authorize. But when I added [Authorize] attr into my controller, I get error:

Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

All I need that my backend app only check scope or role from JWT token and allow to get some data. I know that JWT is correct and react app login user without any problems.

Similar issue to this one:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/validating-token-signatures-in-asp-net-core/108226

Comment: Did you register your API in you AD tenant?

Comment: you mean my .net core app?

Comment: Yes, your .net core app

Comment: nope. I registered only my react app
if i need to register net core app, I dont understand all flow... 
Now its react -> get token from azureAD -> add header Authorize -> net core app request
net core app should only check roles and claims from jwt token and thats it. What is wrong in this flow?

Comment: Also, do you have the correct signing key in your .net core app?

Comment: Try to add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`
Instead of `[Authorize]`

Comment: @DFord My react app successfully logged in into azure ad. SigningKey - where I should get it? I have only jwt token added in header as Authorize.

Comment: @Carl Zhao, already tried. I have error in my backend app as :

IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: 'kg2LYs2T0CTjIfj4rt6JIynen38', InternalId: 'b66e6a03-9cca-4332-8780-263af82b519b'. , KeyId: kg2LYs2T0CTjIfj4rt6JIynen38

Comment: @RomaPavliuk  Please provide the url where you get the access token.

Comment: @CarlZhao 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: How did you set up the `scope`? I saw that you have links to similar questions. Have you also registered two applications through AAD (MobileApp as a native application and WebAPI as a web application/api)?

Comment: @CarlZhao scope params in my react app:
scope: "openid profile email"
In the beginning i have only 1 app in Azure AD. And my reactapp logged in and all works fine. When I tried to send request into my api, I have a problems. 
Then I created one more app in my Azure AD for api and linked with client app. But issue still here( I tried different ways in my api , but without any result.

Comment: You need to set the scope to: `api://{api app client id}/.default`

Comment: @CarlZhao when I add only this one scope, I have error:
ErrorResponse: AADSTS700053:+response_type+'id_token'+requires+the+'openid'+scope
When add openId, next error:
oidc-client.min.js:1 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Go to AAD>your api app>Expose an API  and provide a screenshot.

Comment: @CarlZhao here I have only one scope: api://b7201ea4-a343-41de-baf2-cbc2c48ac2c9/access_as_user
And this scope I have added into my react app as scope.
After that I have error with 401 when trying to login

Comment: @RomaPavliuk  Try: 1. Set the scope to: api://b7201ea4-a343-41de-baf2-cbc2c48ac2c9/access_as_user. 2. Add client app to api app.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U5s4.png

Comment: @CarlZhao
added to api app -> Expose an API -> Authorized client applications -> new record with clientId(id of my client app)
still 401 when my react app trying to login on  graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo

Comment: @CarlZhao when i changed scope into api://b7201ea4-a343-41de-baf2-cbc2c48ac2c9/access_as_user., I can't login.

Comment: Issue was fixed! thank you)

Comment: @RomaPavliuk How was it resolved? Experiencing the same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize the comments and post it as an answer:

Usually the 401 error means that the audience of your token does not match your api. When you use the token to call the api, you will receive a 401 unauthorized error. The access token is issued based on the audience, so you must Make sure to set the scope to your api when you request the token. Of course you can also parse the token, check the `aud` claim, and make sure it is the api you want to call.

When you expose an api protected by Azure, then you need to set the scope to your custom api, usually `api://{api app client id}/scope name`, and then you need to add the client application to the api application.

[image]

Comment: @RomaPavliuk  You can mark it as an answer to end the thread ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) or you can post your own answer.